# Asymptotic distribution of ratio of two coordinates of random unit-vector

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

Let $n$ be a large positive integer. Let $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ be uniform on the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ and define $R:=X_1/X_2$.

> **Question.** *What is the distribution of $R$ ?*

**Note.** I'm really only interested in estimating $\mathbb P(R \le r)$ upto an error which goes to zero with $n$, uniformly in $r$.

### Observations

- The CDF of $X_j$ converges pointwise to the CDF of $N(0,1/n)$, with a uniform error of $\mathcal O(1/n^\alpha)$.
- If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent gaussians of zero mean and same variance, then $Z_1/Z_2$ has Cauchy distribution.

Thus my guess is that asymptotic distribution of $R$ is Cauchy.

Comment: it looks like there is a $R$, $1\over R$ symmetry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sought pdf is obtained by
$$
p(R)=C\int_0^\infty\cdots\int_0^\infty dx_1\cdots dx_n\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-1\right)\delta(R-x_1/x_2)\ .
$$
Define the auxiliary object
$$
p(R,t)=C\int_0^\infty\cdots\int_0^\infty dx_1\cdots dx_n\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-t\right)\delta(R-x_1/x_2)\ ,
$$
and take its Laplace transform w.r.t. $t$
$$
\hat p(R,s)=\int_0^\infty dt e^{-st}p(R,t)=C\int_0^\infty\cdots\int_0^\infty dx_1\cdots dx_n e^{-s\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\delta(R-x_1/x_2)\ .
$$
Use the delta to kill the $x_1$ integral, as $\delta(R-x_1/x_2)=x_2\delta(x_1-R x_2)$, to obtain
$$
\hat p(R,s)=C\int_0^\infty dx_2~x_2 e^{-x_2^2(s+s R^2)}\left[\int_0^\infty dx e^{-s x^2}\right]^{n-2}=\frac{C}{2s(R^2+1)}(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{n-2}\frac{1}{s^{(n-2)/2}}\ .$$
All you have to do is to take the inverse Laplace transform of this result (Mathematica can do that), set $t=1$, and compute the normalisation constant $C$, such that $\int_0^\infty dR p(R)=1$. The $R$-dependence is anyway independent of this procedure, and it yields indeed a Cauchy pdf for all $n$.

EDIT: if you allow $x_i$ to be also negative, the procedure above also works with $\int_0^\infty \to\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, and using $\delta(R-x_1/x_2)=|x_2|\delta(x_1-R x_2)$.

Comment: Great, thanks (upvoted). https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5B1+%2F+%28R%5E2%2Bs%29%28pi%2F%284s%29%29%5E%28%28n-2%29%2F2%29%2Cs%2C1%5D tells me that in the general case, $p_n(R)$ involves $E_{-(n-2)/2}(-R^2)$, where $E_{k}$ is the exponential integral function of order $k$. The name of the game is then computing the asymptotics of $E_{-(n-2)/2}(-R^2)$ (i.e for large $n$), and comparing the whole thing with the Cauchy density $1/(\pi(R^2+1))$. I'll try to pull this off.

Comment: yeah, bear in mind that the constant $C$ also depends on $n$, though ... there should be a more direct way to get the asymptotics for large $n$, if that is what you really need... I'll think about that

Comment: Ya, but those constants are probably related to the volume / surface area of something, that can be recognized in the unnormalized form, and cancelled out (modulo absolute constants).

Comment: Sure, actually C^{-1} is simply equal to the very first integral in my answer without the $\delta(R-x_1/x_2)$ bit ...

Comment: I think using the convolution theorem would be a better way to go than using Exponential integral functions ... essentially, the Laplace transform is the product of $F(s)=1/(R^2+s)$ and $G(s)=1/s^{(n-2)/2}$ (if I didn't make mistakes), both of which have elementary ILTs. So writing the convolution integral and studying the asymptotics of it for large $n$ may be a better way to go ...

Comment: Indeed. That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @dohmatob my apologies, I had missed a factor of $s$ in the exponent when computing $\exp(-s x_1^2)$. The final result is actually much simpler, and indeed gives a Cauchy pdf for all $n$ (not just asymptotically for large $n$) ... please double check!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, and thanks for the correction. Indeed, it is Cauchy! It turns out this can be done in a more direct way: $R_S:=X_1/X_2$ has the same distribution as $R_G:=Z_1/Z_2$ (where $(Z_1,Z_2) \sim N(0,I_2)$, $X$ has the same distribution as $X=Z/\|Z\|$, where $Z \sim N(0,I_n)$. But $R_G$ can be shown to have Cauchy distribution by elementary calculations. Don't know why I didn't think of this one-liner until now. Anyways, the real take away here is that you've taugh me how to use the Laplace transform to compute otherwise horrible spherical expectations. This is a big win!

Comment: And with the Laplace trick, one can provide elegant solutions to otherwise laborious problems like so https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359643/marginal-density-of-uniform-spherical-distribution/406981#406981. Thanks showing me this!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this can be done in a more direct way: $R_S:=X_1/X_2$ has the same distribution as $R_G:=Z_1/Z_2$ (where $(Z_1,Z_2) \sim N(0,I_2)$, $X$ has the same distribution as $X=Z/\|Z\|$, where $Z \sim N(0,I_n)$. But $R_G$ can be shown to have Cauchy distribution by [elementary calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation)!

Don't know why I didn't think of this earlier...